Template suggestion for node view mode is not used when using a preprocess hook
I'm trying to figure out why my suggested template for a node view mode is not being used.
I have two different bundles that I would like to share the same view mode template hence I would like to use the template file node--plain-teaser.html.twig listed in the suggestions from twig debug below.
   * node--view--latest-section-articles--block-1.html.twig
   * node--view--latest-section-articles.html.twig
   * node--943556--plain-teaser.html.twig
   * node--943556.html.twig
   * node--article--plain-teaser.html.twig
   * node--article.html.twig
   * node--plain-teaser.html.twig
   x node.html.twig

If I name my template node--article--plain-teaser.html.twig then there's no problem.
But if I try to name it node--plain-teaser.html.twig it skips straight to node.html.twig even though it's listed in the suggestions and present at this path /themes/custom/<theme>/templates/node/node--plain-teaser.html.twig.
I have a hook_preprocess_HOOK(): my_module_preprocess_node__article__plain_teaser() that if I remove this preprocess hook it will load node--plain-teaser.html.twigbut if I use the preprocess hook it will load node.html.twig.
Is this as intented? I would really like to be able to use the preprocess hook.
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 *
 * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityMalformedException
 */
function my_module_preprocess_node__article__plain_teaser(&$variables): void {
  $element = $variables['elements'];
  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $article */
  $article = $element['#node'];
  /** @var \Drupal\some_module\Service\ArticleProcessorService $articleProcessor */
  $articleProcessor = \Drupal::service('some_module.article_processor');

  $mediaTypes = [];
  foreach ($article->get('article_media')->referencedEntities() as $media) {
    if ($media->bundle() === 'image' && empty($mediaTypes['image'])) {
      $mediaTypes['image'] = $media;
    }
    elseif ($media->bundle() === 'video' && empty($mediaTypes['video'])) {
      $mediaTypes['video'] = $media;
    }
  }

  $metaSettings = [
    'iconVisible' => FALSE,
    'backgroundColorHex' => FALSE,
    'themeOverride' => FALSE,
    'showLockedStatus' => FALSE,
  ];

  my_module_article_prepare_data($variables, $article, $articleProcessor, $variables['view_mode'], $metaSettings, $mediaTypes);
}


I might just have had progress. I renamed the preprocess hook from my_module_preprocess_node__article__plain_teaser to my_module_preprocess_node__plain_teaser and that seems to make it find the right template file.
Going to do some further work before I mark this as a possible answer.

The preprocess hooks should not include the bundle for this to work. Naming it my_module_preprocess_node__plain_teaser made the preprocess hook work for multiple bundles and also made the template suggestion use the correct template.
Though any use of hook_preprocess_node__article() without the view mode will still cause the same problem and must be avoided. I will gladly take any suggestions if this could be solved better.
